# Bundle install is failing with gem nokogiri error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I'm running my app on ubuntu, ruby 2.7.8 using rbenv

When I do `bundle install` I received error

> An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.8.1), and Bundler
> cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

Nokogiri installation attempt **[all failed]**

1. `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
2. `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' -- --use-system-libraries`
3. `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8.1' -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2`
4. `bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries` then `bundle install`

Got this error during installation (I cut short because error too long)

```
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/ext/nokogiri
/home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/bin/ruby -I /home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20240116-50988-10fdguc.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include\=/usr/include/libxml2
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for exsltFuncRegister() in libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for xmlHasFeature()... yes
checking for xmlFirstElementChild()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/ext/nokogiri
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/ext/nokogiri
make "DESTDIR="
compiling html_document.c
In file included from /home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./html_document.h:4,
                 from html_document.c:1:
/home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function ‘rb_scan_args_set’:
/home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2594:40: warning: conversion to ‘long unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
         memcpy(ptr, argv, sizeof(VALUE)*argc);
                                        ^
/home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1763:54: note: in definition of macro ‘memcpy’
 #define memcpy(p1,p2,n) ruby_nonempty_memcpy(p1, p2, n)
                                                      ^
In file included from ./html_document.h:4:0,
                 from html_document.c:1:
./nokogiri.h: At top level:
./nokogiri.h:39:0: warning: "MAYBE_UNUSED" redefined
 #  define MAYBE_UNUSED(name) name __attribute__((unused))
 
In file included from /home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:0,
                 from /home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./html_document.h:4,
                 from html_document.c:1:
/home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/include/ruby-2.7.0/x86_64-linux/ruby/config.h:161:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MAYBE_UNUSED(x) __attribute__ ((__unused__)) x
 
In file included from /home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./html_document.h:4,
                 from html_document.c:1:
html_document.c: In function ‘new’:
/home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2510:48: warning: cast discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wcast-qual]
        (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars), (char *)fmt, varc)
                                                ^
......
                                                ^
/home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2342:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args0’
         rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_document.c:508:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args’
   rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "03", &mode, &incl_ns, &with_comments);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_document.c:535:15: warning: cast discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wcast-qual]
       ns[i] = (xmlChar*) ptr;
               ^
Makefile:245: recipe for target 'xml_document.o' failed
make: *** [xml_document.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/gem_make.out
```

I have `libxslt-dev` and `libxml2-dev` installed. Tried out all the solutions I found on the internet but nothing work. I don't know what else to do. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `Results logged to /home/adam/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/gem_make.out`. Please scan the file for errors (not warnings), and paste the errors into your question.

Comment: @Casper the content of the file is exactly the same as the one above

Comment: Possible dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233453/error-installing-nokogiri-gem

Comment: I only see warnings, no errors. Have you tried to search for the text "error" or "fail" in gem_make.out?

Comment: Can you install a newer version? Like 1.6.8 instead of 1.6.8.1, or even 1.6?

Comment: @m26a I tried it and still failed

Comment: Try `sudo apt install libgmp-dev`. I had to do this last time I installed nokogiri.